# Edge detection using Satellite Rectified  Multispectral  Imagery

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to apply `sobel` and `canny` edge detection methods using MATLAB to a rectified Multispectral Satellite imagery, but it couldn't detect the edges. The results were just not as edges but as dotted noise all over.

What should I do to detect the delicate boundaries from the rectified multispectral imagery? Is there any special technique needed?

Comment: Going to be hard to answer without seeing the images.

Comment: What kind of image? Monochromatic or multispectral?

Comment: its a rectified Multispectral image

Comment: @Adams Upload your images somewhere and post a link!

Comment: Questions: (1) how thick/wide is the edge profile, in pixels? (2) What is the contrast of the edge? (both absolute graylevel and relative e.g. variance measured across the edge vs. measured on one side of the edge)

Comment: Voting to close. I'll vote to reopen if more info is given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're doing everything else right (with how you're calling the `edge` command etc.) this can happen if the images are particularly noisy.  You might consider smoothing (such as filtering with a Gaussian or other kernel.)  This should make the noise go away in favor of other more meaningful edges.

You should also try play with the thresholds.

Comment: Thans for the guidance but how to go about with the design of the Gaussian Kernel? I need more technical guidance on this so that i can apply it to detect the boundaries of some fields on the CIR image.

Comment: Just curious, how can you claim this is the answer is you haven't implemented it?  Also, my suggestion is to try things first by looking something up on Google and reading about it before you ask very open-ended questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

As an option, you can save your RGB images and try to open them with the Outliner utility 
http://outliner.codeplex.com/
This utility uses an alternative method of edge detection that works best on color images.

Comment: i used this utiity and the edges were clearly shown.Thanks. But i need to know how it is done pls

Comment: you can find several document files (MS Word format) in the Documentation tab: http://outliner.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: but the full detail is in the source code (MS Visual C++), available for download.